# MVC - ADFS Authentication - ADFS redirects to localhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, authentication, visual-studio-2015, adfs

I'm trying to publish a new MVC application to an Azure App Service. The app uses ADFS single sign on authentication, I have added a relying party trust on the ADFS server and can login when testing on localhost.

After publishing to my app service and trying to login it redirects to ADFS but once authenticating it redirects to localhost.

I have tried to research the issue and found the following blog and screenshot:
http://rickrainey.com/2014/07/28/authenticating-with-organizational-accounts-and-azure-active-directory/

[image: Enable Oranisational Authentication]

But in Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 my settings look like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfZEF.jpg

And the following question (which is relevant to VS 2013) points to enabling organisational authentication, but the comment on the accepted answer says that the option has been removed in VS 2015.
[Published ASP.NET MVC 5 app with Organizational Account authentication Redirects back to localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27887947/published-asp-net-mvc-5-app-with-organizational-account-authentication-redirects)

My question is what are the steps in VS 2015 or 2017 to enable organisational authentication and stop my app redirecting to localhost once ADFS has authenticated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much googling I found the problem wasn't enabling organisational authentication, it's actually in ADFS settings for my relying party trust.

You have to edit the relying party trust on your ADFS server. Right click > Properties > Endpoints > Add a WS-Federation Endpoint pointing to your https root site URL > Tick set as default.

[image: WS-Federation Endpoint]

My site now works and authenticates with ADFS.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather recommend you to look into the adfs configuration here

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/identity/ad-fs/development/single-page-application-with-ad-fs#registering-the-public-client-in-ad-fs

have a look at the redirected adfs url:

https://youradfsserver/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44388%2F......
you have a query parameter named: redirect_uri which is probably built from the SingIn Method in your account controller

```
    public void SignIn()
    {
        // Send an OpenID Connect sign-in request.
        if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext()
.Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties 
{ RedirectUri = "/" },
                OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }
    }
```

make sure it is not any absolute URL

Comment: I expect the app is more likely to be using ws-federation via OWIN middleware. The relying party trust in AD FS is likely configured with an endpoint that points to localhost. You'll need to change the RP trust endpoint to match the destination where app is hosted in azure app services.